# When can I call a function in C as a system call

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

In C programming language, I can use both `fopen()`, `open()` for file operations.

Is `fopen()` is a system call or not? If no why?

Is `open()` is a system call or not? If yes why?

Comment: Check manual and compare with *your* definition of "system call".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General Information**

- A *system call* is basically an interface of your application to the OS kernel.
- System calls are usually wrapped by the *wrapper function* provided by the platform's standard library.

Sometimes the system call name and the wrapper function names are same, sometimes they are not.

Usually, the *wrapper functions* provided by the standard library provides some extra feature and/or sanity checking/ error checking for the underlying *system call*.

system calls are the bare minimum calls that is passed to the kernel, which executes in *kernel-mode* and returns the required result to the *user-space* application.

For each kernel versions, there are defined set of system calls available and are usually represented by a number associated with each call. Ready referecnce : [arch/i386/kernel/entry.S file](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/cs108/rootkits/entry.S) (look for `sys_call_table`)

OTOH, the library functions, provided by standard [or non-standard] libraries are simple APIs which are used to provide access to various functions , including system calls in a bit easy way for the developer. These are used to hide some complex parts, provide some additional checks, some error handling and finally calls the internal function, mostly underlying *system calls*.

---

**Answer to your question**

`open()` is a system call.

`fopen()` is a wrapper provided by the standard library [linux glibc, for example].

Check more details in [`syscalls`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) manual page.

Comment: calling fopen() a wrapper of open() may not be appropriate. The main purpose of fopen() is implement the standard C lib function, not to wrap open(). A wrapper should expose as much function as the wrapped one. The real wrapper is mostly a assembly code like :ENTRY(read)
    movl    $__NR_read, %eax
    syscall...
    ret
END(read)

Answer (score 0):

`open()` is a system call. `man 2 open` gives you the details, and system calls are in section 2.

System calls are the lowest-level functionality of an application. They tend to be a no-frills API, providing the bare minimum to accomplish a task. A system call is a request from your application to the kernel to interact with something, like a filesystem, or a network socket.

The main distinguishing feature of a  *system call* is that you leave the user-mode context where your application code is running, and transition to kernel-mode, where the kernel code executes to handle that request for you.

There is a lot of information available on the topic. I suggest you start with [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20system%20call).

---

`fopen()` is a library call, provided by your libc. `man 3 fopen` gives you the details. Many of these library calls serve as wrappers to the system calls. `fopen` makes an `open()` call under the hood, but also sets up the `FILE` stream - an abstraction that makes your life as a developer easier.

For example, with the `write` system call, you pass it a pointer to some data, and a length - that's all. With the `FILE` streams, you can `fwrite`, `fprintf`, etc. These streams also provide *buffering* which improves the performance of your application. System calls incur a a fair amount of overhead, to make the user-kernel mode switch; this buffering basically combines multiple `fwrite` / `fprintf` calls to speed things up.

See also:

- [What the role of libc(glibc) in our linux app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372872/what-the-role-of-libcglibc-in-our-linux-app)
- [What's the difference between "C system calls" and "C library routines"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572942)
- [Difference between system calls and library functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/)

Answer (score 0):

`open()` is a system call and `fopen()` is a library function.

For more details see the man page of [open()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) and man page of [fopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/system-calls-library-functions/) for difference between the library and system call. The latter link says:

> Well, the answer to this is the fact that fopen() is a library function which provides buffered I/O services for opening a file while open() is a system call that provides non-buffered I/O services. Though open() function is also available for applications to use but application should avoid using it directly.